# Get tag of currently displayed fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I searched to get the currently displayed fragment and found some answers. I tried `findFragmentById`.It returns null. I'm using `FrameLayout` in the fragment's xml. Not `<fragment>`. So maybe that's why it returns null. I use the `id` of the `<FrameLayout>` in `findFragmentById`.

Someone told me to use tags. But I can't figure out how to use the tags you set while replacing the fragment to check if the current fragment has the tag.

If a particular fragment is displayed which is selected from nav drawer I need to exit the app by `onBackPressed()` by clearing all the activities in the stack. I just need to see if the currently displayed fragment is that particular fragment.

Can you someone please explain with an example. I've been doing this for days and can't figure out.

Edit. I have not posted any code because I just want an example. I posted a question about `findFragmentById` returning null already and someone suggested me to use tags and I can't figure out using the tag to check if it's the current fragment.

Comment: Can you at least read the entire question before downvoting? It's just been a second since I posted it. Please explain why you are downvoting. I think this is a legitimate question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope this can help you

At the time of calling fragment set a unique tag to each fragment like

```
      Fragment fragment=new HomeFragment();
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment,"Home").commit();
//home is the tag
```

In your MainActivity's onBackPressed method check that particular fragment is visible or not

```
 Fragment hm=getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("Home");
     if(hm!=null)
     {
      if(hm.isVisible())
       {
         //exit your application
          MainActivity.this.finish(); 
       }
     }
```