# Failing to set tags on Android Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

Help me on this question on treehouse. How do i retrieve tags?

https://teamtreehouse.com/community/can-you-please-make-sure-that-we-retrieve-by-tag-and-every-time-we-add-or-set-our-fragment-in-our-fragment-transactions

Answer (score 0):

Just use `getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(String)`.

Related:

[Find Fragment by tag name in Container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16918854/find-fragment-by-tag-name-in-container)

[Get Fragment by Tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24798145/get-fragment-by-tag)

[Get tag of currently displayed fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35078155/get-tag-of-currently-displayed-fragment)

[Uses of fragment tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13509495/uses-of-fragment-tags)